# NativeScript Splash Screen time

Tags: android, nativescript, splash-screen, angular2-nativescript

I am using nativescript starter app with angular.

It is the barebones starter app that is created by the cli.

what I want to know is that how can I change the splash screen time for the app.

I went through the docs here https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/blob/master/publishing/creating-launch-screens-android.md

But was unable to find any mention of splash screen time.

Comment: Hey, it could be just language barrier, but, what do you mean by `changing` the splash screen time? Do you mean the startup time of the application, or the length for which the static image is showing? 
Perhaps you want to change the `theme`?

Comment: I mean the length of time for which the image is displayed..I have the default starter app..can you mention What can I add and where

Answer (score 2):

You need to first understand that the initial image will display only for as long as it takes for the app to load initially. Having said that,you can neither shorten the time (unless you optimize the application - load resources lazily for example), nor extend it naturally.

Beginning with NativeScript 2.4 android apps will be created with snapshots enabled by default. That means shorter initial loading times.

That should be a very noticeable improvement for new apps, especially those written in Angular2